# Animated GIFs not working in Craft with ImageMagick installed

Tags: image-transforms, imagick, gif

When I upload a GIF I either get the first frame or a garbled image (https://share.getcloudapp.com/L1u7BXrA).

Looking around at similar questions, Craft needs ImageMagick installed to properly transform GIFs after upload.

I can confirm ImageMagick is installed and being used as the image driver (https://share.getcloudapp.com/BluZKGYw).

Server has php-imagick and imagemagick installed.

I have 'imageDriver' => 'imagick' set in general.php

Using Amazon S3 to store images.

Anything else I should be trying? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up applying this configuration to config > general.php so GIFs aren't transformed.

```
'transformGifs' => false
```

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#transformgifs

Answer (score 0):

Guessing it's a bug in either php-imagick (3.4.0-rc6 is 4 years old https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick) or ImageMagick (6.8.9-9 is 5 years old https://imagemagick.org/download/releases/).

I'd try updating those to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Update: I have the gifs uploading correctly, the problem seems to be with transforming the image on page render. My machine starts to struggle and nothing is rendered where the GIF should be. One option would be to just not transform GIFs. Wondering if there's a better option.